# Iterate through rows - Google Sheets - merge documents

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a document that contains 4 columns - each with a link to a Google Doc file.
I have hacked together some code that merges the documents together, so that Column 2, 3 and 4 get appended to the document in Column 1.

I now just need some help in turning it into a loop so it will loop through all of the rows (there will be around 500 in the finished document)

The code also breaks if there is a missing file in any of the columns, in an ideal world I would like it just to skip that file and move on to the next column.

Can anyone help (And yes, I know the code sucks)

```
function mergeGoogleDocs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');// access specific sheet
  var row = sh.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  var original = sh.getRange(row,1).getValue();
  var arabic = sh.getRange(row,2).getValue();
  var islamic = sh.getRange(row,3).getValue();
  var smallsteps = sh.getRange(row,4).getValue();
  var docIDs = [original,arabic,islamic,smallsteps];
  var baseDoc = DocumentApp.openById(docIDs[0]);

  var body = baseDoc.getActiveSection();

  for (var i = 1; i < docIDs.length; ++i ) {
    var otherBody = DocumentApp.openById(docIDs[i]).getActiveSection();
    var totalElements = otherBody.getNumChildren();
    for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
      var element = otherBody.getChild(j).copy();
      var type = element.getType();
      if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH )
        body.appendParagraph(element);
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE )
        body.appendTable(element);
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM )
        body.appendListItem(element);
      else
        throw new Error("Unknown element type: "+type);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does you sheet have headers?

Comment: It would be helpful to see a sample sheet so that I can see what the data looks like.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ufr0DYZcFpobHOPuFtkFKbSWQHJfBmqSdeegDaGPuFc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Data does have headers - there will be between 2 and 4 documents to merge together.

Answer (score 1):

Your function seems to be doing more.  I'm not sure why you description was basically to open the document in column1 and append the data in colums 2 through 4 which is what this function does.

```
function mergeGoogleDocs() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  //assuming no headers for now
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    var doc=DocumentApp.openById(r[0]);
    var body=doc.getBody();
    body.appendParagraph(r[1]);
    body.appendParagraph(r[2]);
    body.appendParagrsph(r[3]);
    lsh.appendRow([r])
    Logger.log(i+1);//just to keep track of how many iterations we get before a possible timeout
    doc.saveAndClose();
  });
}
```

Let me where I went wrong and I'll fix it. Opening 500 documents appending data and closing the files most likely will result in causing the script to timeout so pay attention to how many get done and we can perform the process in batches.

Comment: The columns contain a link to another Google Doc, not data to be appended to the document.

Comment: Hi, tried this and it appended the value of the columns to the end of the document referenced in column 1 - but the columns are links to different google docs - ideally I want to merge the entire content of that to the initial doc